# Adding comments in a fish shell function file

Tags: comments, fish

How do I add comments to a function a write for fish shell? Is it `//`. I can't seem to be able to tell. When I use `//`, sometimes when the function fails, it changes the user to the root directory.

Comment: Although I can't see it documented anywhere, the fish comment character, like other shells, is `#`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The comment sign is `#`, as glenn jackman suggested.